# How to set actions for $resource in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a simple service using service in angularjs and I want to make a simple GET call and currently my service function is

```
angular.module('mean.system').factory('Config', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('config');
}]);
```

and I use that function by calling

```
Config.query(function(config){
    console.log(config);
});
```

But I get an error saying that it expect array but got an object. I want to add the option isArray:false in the service and tried

```
return $resource('config',{},{isArray:false});
```

What is the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Config.get instead Config.query